# How to append due date to a list in Sharepoint?

Tags: wss-3.0

How to append due date to a list in Sharepoint?

I have a list in WSS 3.0 where many people work on a particular task. So Due Date goes on changing frequently. But I need to keep a record of Due Dates. How to do it?

Please help!

saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the versionning on the list and use the version history to get the last due dates.  You could also use another field that, with an event handler, could be filled with the modified values and you could keep them in a certain format.